# Requirements for forward iterator iterator_traits::reference

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to figure out exactly what requirements are made on forward_iterators' `reference` types.  In the obvious cases you'll have `value_type = T;` and `reference = T&;`.  Reading the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) on forward iterator requirements, I saw

```
Expression  Return      Equivalent expression
*i++        reference   value_type& temp=*i; ++i; return temp;
```

`std::vector<bool>` shows that the "equivalent expression" isn't always valid since it returns a proxy object:

```
std::vector<bool> v(10);
auto i = v.begin();
std::vector<bool>::iterator::value_type& temp = *i; // error
// can't bind bool& to std::_Bit_reference
```

The equivalent expression isn't mentioned in the standard that I saw.  The proxy object allows assignment though, which might be the key to conformance.

Outside of just all around trying to nail down the requirements, my specific question concerns knowing whether or not having `value_type` == `reference` where neither is a reference or supports assignment, would work with the standard libraries.

Would some `Container<int>` with an `iterator` tagged as `forward_iterator_tag` and `reference == int` be valid?

Comment: C++11 table 109 in §24.2.5/4 gives the following operational semantics for `r++`: `{ X tmp = r; ++r; return tmp; }`, and states the return type should be convertible to `const X&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirements are enumerated in [forward.iterators]:

> A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if
>
> - `X` satisfies the requirements of an input iterator (24.2.3),
> - `X` satisfies the DefaultConstructible requirements (17.6.3.1),
> - if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a const iterator, reference is a reference
>     to `const T`,
> - [...]

So if your container has `reference` == `int`, then it does not meet the requirements of forward iterator. Which I suppose technically makes `vector<bool>::iterator` just an input iterator, even though it's tagged as a random access iterator.

Comment: I suppose I'll just accept that `std::vector<bool>` is a liar.